# Редактирование файла

Tags: php

Всем привет, у меня вопрос про редактирование файла средствами PHP. Использую функцию fopen. Проблема в том, что мне нужно открыть файл и удалить всё что там есть и поместить туда что-то новое, мне подходит режим w+, но вот только

> Открывает файл для чтения и записи; помещает указатель в начало файла и обрезает файл до нулевой длинны. Если файл не существует - пробует его создать.

Мне нужно вернуть false, в случае отсутствия файла, я понимаю что можно так самому проверить на существование файла, но можно ли как либо это исправить чтобы он возвращал false? если можно с примером кода :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите `is_file`. Пример в [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php).

Помните, однако, что работа с файловой системой существенно неатомарна. После проверки на существование файл может появиться или наоборот пропасть, или могут поменяться права доступа, или на месте файла может появиться каталог, так что будьте готовы, что `fopen` отработает с ошибкой.

Кстати, не будет ли вам достаточно режима `w`?

Answer (score 1):

Я так подозреваю, что вам нужна конкурентная запись в файл и вы пытаетесь сделать что-то вроде механизма блокировок.
Единственной атомарной операцией является перемещение (mv) внутри одной файловой системы.
Проверяете существование с помощью is_file, затем создаете временный файл, пишете в него, затем перемещаете с помощью rename.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько правилен такой код?

```
 $file = MAIN."/template/default/".$_POST['FileName'];
 if (!file_exists($file)) {
     error_message('Ошибка!', 'Нет такого файла');
 } else {
     $write = fopen($file, 'w+') or die ("Файла нет!");
     fwrite($write, $_POST['text']) or die ("Что-то не так!");
     echo '<script>alert("Файл сохранён");</script>';
 }
```

Comment: На мой неопытный взгляд, правильно. Но всё же `is_file` немного лучше.

Comment: Да, ещё: а если в `.$_POST['FileName']` будет что-то наподобие `'../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd'`? Значение переменной полностью контролируется юзером.